# How to find the last or next entry using R package data.table and rolling joins

Tags: r, data.table

```
Lets say I have a data table like this.

   customer_id time_stamp value
1:           1        223     4
2:           1        252     1
3:           1        456     3
4:           2        455     5
5:           2        632     2
```

So that customer_id and time_stamp together form a unique key. I want to add some new columns indicating the previous and last values of "value". That is, I want output like this.

```
  customer_id time_stamp value value_PREV value_NEXT
1:           1        223     4         NA          1
2:           1        252     1          4          3
3:           1        456     3          1         NA
4:           2        455     5         NA          2
5:           2        632     2          5         NA
```

I want this to be fast and work with sparse, irregular times. I thought that the data.table rolling join would do it for me. However the rolling join appears to find the last time OR same time. So if you do a rolling join on two copies of the same table (after adding _PREV to the column names of the copy), this doesn't quite work. You can fudge it by adding a tiny number to the time variable of the copy but this is kinda awkward.

Is there a way to do this simply with rollin join or some other data.table method? I've found an efficient way but it still requires about 40 lines of R code. It seems that this could be a one-liner if rolling join could be told to look for the last time NOT including the same time.  Or maybe there is some other neat trick.

Here is the example data.

```
data=data.table(customer_id=c(1,2,1,1,2),time_stamp=c(252,632,456,223,455),value=c(1,2,3,4,5))
data_sorted=data[order(customer_id,time_stamp)]
```

---

This is the code I wrote. Note that the lines putting NA into the ones
where customer_id differ throws a warning and probably needs changing.
I have them commented out below. Anyone have any suggestions for replacing those two lines?

```
add_prev_next_cbind<-function(data,ident="customer_id",timecol="time_stamp",prev_tag="PREV",
                   next_tag="NEXT",sep="_"){
  o=order(data[[ident]],data[[timecol]])
  uo=order(o)
  data=data[o,]
  Nrow=nrow(data)
  Ncol=ncol(data)
  #shift it, put any junk in the first row
  data_prev=data[c(1,1:(Nrow-1)),]
  #shift it, put any junk in the last row
  data_next=data[c(2:(Nrow),Nrow),]
  #flag the rows where the identity changes, these get NA
  prev_diff=data[[ident]] != data_prev[[ident]]
  prev_diff[1]=T
  next_diff=data[[ident]] != data_next[[ident]]  
  next_diff[Nrow]=T
  #change names
  names=names(data)
  names_prev=paste(names,prev_tag,sep=sep)
  names_next=paste(names,next_tag,sep=sep)
  setnames(data_prev,names,names_prev)
  setnames(data_next,names,names_next)
  #put NA in rows where prev and next are from a different ident
  #replace the next two lines with something else
  #data_prev[prev_diff,]<-NA
  #data_next[next_diff,]<-NA
  data_all=cbind(data,data_prev,data_next)
  data_all=data_all[uo,]
  return(data_all)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Update: [#965](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/965) is now implemented in [1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/b8c1b01ac9453750d0e99a388522877eec38f06b). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 5. New function `shift()` implements fast `lead/lag` of *vector*, *list*, *data.frames* or *data.tables*. It takes a `type` argument which can be either *"lag"* (default) or *"lead"* and always returns a list, which makes it very convenient to use it along with `:=` or `set()`. For example: `DT[, (cols) := shift(.SD, 1L), by=id]`. Please have a look at `?shift` for more info.

Now we can therefore do:

```
dt[, c("value_PREV", "value_NEXT") := c(shift(value, 1L, type="lag"), 
                     shift(value, 1L, type="lead")), by=customer_id]
```

---

You don't need a roll join here at all. you can do this with `head` and `tail`. Assuming your `data.table` is DT:

```
setkey(DT, "customer_id")
DT[, list(time_stamp = time_stamp, 
          prev.val = c(NA, head(value, -1)), 
          next.val = c(tail(value, -1), NA)), 
by=customer_id]
#   customer_id time_stamp prev.val next.val
# 1:           1        223       NA        1
# 2:           1        252        4        3
# 3:           1        456        1       NA
# 4:           2        455       NA        2
# 5:           2        632        5       NA
```

**Edit:** Even better:

```
DT[, `:=`(prev.val = c(NA, head(value, -1)), 
          next.val = c(tail(value, -1), NA)), 
          by=customer_id]
```

Comment: That cool! Thanks. Let me see if I can make it work on .SD. I really have many columns (not just value) and would not want to type out each one.

Comment: @user1827975, check my edit. This'll just add the two columns by reference directly.

Comment: Unfortunately that is much slower than my other implementation that uses joins. It appears to be about 4 times slower. However when I have many,many columns it slows down much more.

Answer (score 6):

Yes if I don't want `roll` to equimatch then I also take a little bit off if it's type double, or work with integer and add or subtract 1L.

```
DT = data.table( customer_id=c(1,2,1,1,2), 
                 time_stamp=as.integer(c(252,632,456,223,455)),
                 value=c(1,2,3,4,5))
setkey(DT, customer_id, time_stamp)
DT[ DT[,list(customer_id,time_stamp+1L,value)], value_PREV:=i.value, roll=-Inf]
DT[ DT[,list(customer_id,time_stamp-1L,value)], value_NEXT:=i.value, roll=+Inf]
DT
   customer_id time_stamp value value_PREV value_NEXT
1:           1        223     4         NA          1
2:           1        252     1          4          3
3:           1        456     3          1         NA
4:           2        455     5         NA          2
5:           2        632     2          5         NA
```

To have to take a column subset of `DT` again in `i` like that is a bit awkward, I agree.

Have now filed [FR#2628](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2628&group_id=240&atid=978) to add a new argument `rollequal=TRUE|FALSE`. Then it would be :

```
setkey(DT, customer_id, time_stamp)
DT[ DT, value_PREV:=i.value, roll=-Inf, rollequal=FALSE]
DT[ DT, value_NEXT:=i.value, roll=+Inf, rollequal=FALSE]
```

That would be faster too by avoiding the copy of the `i` columns and not needing to allocate for `time_stamp-1L` and `time_stamp+1L`.

But in this case, it's a self join from `DT` to `DT` and `DT`'s key is unique, so as Arun says, a `roll` join isn't needed.  Maybe a fast shift or lag function is needed to avoid the overhead of `c()` and `head()` or `tail()`, for speed.

Thanks for highlighting!

Comment: Thanks. I have another few ways of doing it. One is to order by (customer_id,time_stamp). Then make a copy of the DT and roll the copy backward/forward one row, and replacing the first/last row with any junk. Then just bind them. Then unsort the result. Then put NAs into the places where the customer id differs between the original and the rolled copies.

Comment: Another way is to calculate the previous/next index and then set the key on one to be this_index and one to be previous/next index and then do a join on these. It seems to me that cbinding would be better since you have already alligned the rows properly.

Comment: @user1827975 Why do you want another way?  Those approaches seem like more code with more copies.