# How can a start date be used to create lagged end dates in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, bigdata

Suppose there is a `date.frame` or `data.table` with observations on millions of individual ids so that a subset looks like this:

```
id <- c(3,3,3,5,5)
data <- c(24,48,60,84,96)
start <- as.Date(c("2006-01-01","2009-12-09","2010-01-02","2006-04-24", "2009-12-09"))
df <- data.frame(id,data,start) ; head(df)
   id data    start
1  3   24 2006-01-01
2  3   48 2009-12-09
3  3   60 2010-01-02
4  5   84 2006-04-24
5  5   96 2009-12-09
```

And we want to create an end date for all of the other covariates in the series so that the end date for period t is the start date for period t+1 minus one day. The catch is 1) this needs to be done by ID and 2) when there isn't a t + 1 then the record gets a marker for ongoing, e.g. "9999-12-31". The product would look like this:

```
df$end <- as.Date(c("2009-12-08","2010-01-01","9999-12-31","2009-12-08",
     "9999-12-31"));head(df)
   id data      start        end
1  3   24 2006-01-01 2009-12-08
2  3   48 2009-12-09 2010-01-01
3  3   60 2010-01-02 9999-12-31
4  5   84 2006-04-24 2009-12-08
5  5   96 2009-12-09 9999-12-31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my `data.table` solution:

```
  library(data.table)
  id <- c(3,3,3,5,5)
  data <- c(24,48,60,84,96)
  start <- as.Date(c("2006-01-01","2009-12-09","2010-01-02","2006-04-24", "2009-12-09"))
  dt <- data.table(id,data,start=start, end=as.Date("9999-01-01"))
  setkey(dt, id, start)
  dt[, end := c(tail(start, -1) - 1, as.Date("9999-01-01")), by="id"]
  id data      start        end
  1:  3   24 2006-01-01 2009-12-08
  2:  3   48 2009-12-09 2010-01-01
  3:  3   60 2010-01-02 9999-01-01
  4:  5   84 2006-04-24 2009-12-08
  5:  5   96 2009-12-09 9999-01-01
```

A short explanation: the `tail` function gets the successor of every row in every ID. Since the last row in each ID doesn't have one, I
add `as.Date("9999-01-01")` here.

The only issue this solution has is that I have to manually add end before with `Date` entries, otherwise the format is `numeric`.

Comment: And just as a comment to my answer...I learned this neat little trick of using `head` and `tail` here on SO. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533805/how-to-find-the-last-or-next-entry-using-r-package-data-table-and-rolling-joins/15533947#15533947), for instance, is one of those answers that uses it. Not sure if it's the only one though or the one where I learned it.